# The server is unable to save the form at this time

Tags: sharepoint-server

I know this is a common question however I feel like this scenario is unique. I have a single user that is receiving this error when posting to a Custom List.  There are times it works just fine for her and there are times she receives the error above in the Title.  I have written some scripts to alert me of peak CPU and Memory utilization and nothing has been alerted from this and I have scoured logs to find nothing.  Database disk space is good. User does not have Download Manager installed. Anonymous Authentication is enabled.  Problem occurs in multiple browsers.  Also the user has permissions to add to this list as indicated by the fact that 70% of the time it works for her.  Desktop Support team insist the networking card and connections are all fine and there are no drops.  When she is submitting the form is a heavy usage time however she is the only user that receives this error out of a couple hundred. I am just looking for somewhere I can look that might be something I haven't considered.

Comment: How about the CPU and memory of the user's computer? You also need to check them. And also check ULS log to check if there is something about this issue.

Comment: I have checked ULS logs but nothing that I can decipher in there that seems to be related.  The Users PC is interesting I will have to get desktop support to monitor that at the time of the form submit.  I am thinking its more of a long shot but its worth looking into.